# Discord.js: MessageAttachment is not defined

Tags: discord.js

I'm having trouble making my bot filter messages and respond with a local file from my computer. Here is the code:

```js
      client.on("message", msg => {
      console.log(msg.content);
      let wordArray = msg.content.split(" ")
      console.log(wordArray)

      let filterWords = ['test']

      for(var i = 0; i < filterWords.length; i++) {
        if(wordArray.includes(filterWords[i])) {
          msg.delete()
          // Create the attachment using MessageAttachment
          const attachment = new MessageAttachment('cbcfilter.png');
          msg.channel.send(attachment)  
        }
      }
    });
```

It gives me this error message:

```
    ReferenceError: MessageAttachment is not defined
        at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/DShirriff/cbcbot/bot.js:108:26)
        at Client.emit (events.js:323:22)
        at MessageCreateAction.handle (/Users/DShirriff/cbcbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
        at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/Users/DShirriff/cbcbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
        at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/Users/DShirriff/cbcbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
        at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/Users/DShirriff/cbcbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:435:22)
        at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/Users/DShirriff/cbcbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
        at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users/DShirriff/cbcbot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
        at WebSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
        at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/Users/DShirriff/cbcbot/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:801:20)
```

Am I an idiot and missing a simple parentheses, or should I look for a different form of this line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `MessageAttachment`.

If you're using `require` to import discord.js then you can do:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('cbcfilter.png');
```

If you're using `import` then you can do:

```js
import { MessageAttachment } from 'discord.js'
const attachment = new MessageAttachment('cbcfilter.png');
```

---

**Side note**: you don't have to construct a `MessageAttachment` you can just do

```js
msg.channel.send({files: ['cbcfilter.png']})
```

OR

```js
msg.channel.send({
files: [{
    attachment: 'entire/path/to/cbcfilter.png',
    name: 'cbcfilter.png'
  }]
})
```

Comment: thanks! it worked and seemed much easier than before.

Comment: did this get removed in v14?

Answer (score 0):

In discord.js v14 its been changed to AttachmentBuilder

```
    return await interaction.editReply({
        content: responseText, 
        ephemeral: true,
        files: [new AttachmentBuilder(Buffer.from(codeResponseText), {name: 'codes.txt'})]
    });
```